# regex to replace all occurances text, uppercase first character in a file using c#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to rename all my sql tables, having the first character upper case.

So:

```
[blahField] [int] NOT NULL,
```

should be converted to:

```
[BlahField] [int] NOT NULL,
```

(it doesn't matter if [int] becomes [Int].

I am just using a c# console application to do this quickly.

Comment: I assume you want a single answer verse 26 '[a' -> '[A' type answers?

Comment: @simeon sorry I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want:

```
string s = "[blahField] [int] NOT NULL,";
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"^\W*\w", new MatchEvaluator(match => match.Value.ToUpper()));
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
[BlahField] [int] NOT NULL,
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "[blahField] [int] NOT NULL,";
string pattern = @"\[(.+?)]";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern,
                    m => "[" +
                        m.Groups[1].Value.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper()
                        + m.Groups[1].Value.Substring(1)
                        + "]"
                );
```

This will return [Int] but you said that was ok.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
public static string FixIt(string s) {
   return s.Substring(0, 1) + Char.ToUpper(s[1]) + s.Substring(2);
}
```

or even

```
return "[" + Char.ToUpper(s[1]) + s.Substring(2);
```

Regex seems like overkill here.

Comment: the content is coming from a file, and the content is not all in order so to speak.

Answer (score 0):

I assume it's only the first "[blabla]" that needs to be uppercased...

Otherwise, ignore this answer :)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(DoTheMrBlah("[blahField] [int] NOT NULL,"));
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static string DoTheMrBlah(string mrBlahMe)
{
    Match m = Regex.Match(mrBlahMe, @"\[([a-z]){1}([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\](.+)");
    if (m.Success)
    {
        char upperme = m.Groups[1].Value.ToUpper()[0];
        return string.Format("[{0}{1}]{2}", upperme, m.Groups[2], m.Groups[3]);
    }
    else return mrBlahMe;
}
```

Comment: You may want to use a couple of negated character classes: `@"\[([a-z])[^]]+][^.]"`
The first one will allow for a better range of characters in the table name, and the second will let it skip over everything except the last segment of a multi-part identifier (e.g. [dbo].[myTable]).  Plus they perform a little better.

Comment: Good to know, thanks :) Won't change the answer tough, since mrblah doesn't seems to care about it ;)